# What is the time complexity of kruskal's algorithm for an adjacency matrix?

Tags: algorithm

Is it O(eloge) or is it O(V^2) since the whole matrix has to be iterated over to retrieve the edges in order for them to be sorted?

Answer (score 2):

It's O(V<sup>2</sup> + E log E), because it takes O(V<sup>2</sup>) to find the edges, and O(E log E) to sort them.

Note that this is at least O(V<sup>2</sup>), but no more than O(V<sup>2</sup> log E), and in the worst case of dense graphs it is the same as O(E log E), because V<sup>2</sup> is O(E) in those cases.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!